# How to increase the size of filelinks content element in Typo3?

Tags: typo3

The content element file-links now accepts 10 files max. How to increase them ?

Typo3 Version: 4.4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extension that solves your problem here:

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/icti_ext_filelinks/current/

Comment: @Sivakumar After your question is properly answered you should choose the best answer by clicking the icon to the left of the answer.

Comment: I'm setting 200 to max_items and size. Still, Typo3 doesn't allow me to save when I add more than 100 files. What might be wrong?

Comment: Ignore my comment. DAM Filelinks was overwriting max_items.

Answer (score 3):

- TYPO3 Backend Modul "Admin Tools" select "configuration".
- Select "TCA" in the select box at the top. Then you can see the Typo Configuration Array.
- Select (click on the small arrow) "tt_content", then "columns", then "media" then "config".
- Now you can see the "maxitems". If you now click on the entry "maxitems" you will get an php code ($TCA['tt_content']['columns']['media']['config']['maxitems'] = 10;)
- TYPO3 4.5 or newer: change the value and save, before 4.5 you need to do the next two steps:
- Copy this code, change the value and insert into typo3conf/extTables.php
- check if $typo_db_extTableDef_script = 'extTables.php'; is set in your localconf.php

Now you should be able to just change any TCA entry.

Have fun:)

Comment: In my book the better answer. No mysterious extra extension needed and you get to learn how to manipulate the TCA without touching any code. Thanks!